# Crystal Reports Font Issue

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 10.2 with VS2005. When I view the report in browser it seems ok, but after printing report it shows smaller font size. Any solution to this except making font size larger in crystal designing. I am using window.print for printing report without exporting to pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

Browser viewing is different from the print view. If you print any normal page then also it's font look is different from the viewing page. In crystal report when you select the text,textbox,formula field and then right click there is properties option in which you can set the font size,color,type.

You can set the crystal report page setting through the right click on crystal report design grid place and select Print option where you set your report printing setting.

One more thing remain. You apply the css or theme for the crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug and the bug also affects CR bundled version of VS 2005.

After googling, I found few answers which goes closely, but nothing says a solution for VS 2005 specifically. This below one didnt help me and hope it would help you

http://search.sap.com/notes?id=0001207181&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031323037313831

The rest are below:

http://mdn.morovia.com/kb/Font-size-decreases-exporting-PDF-Crystal-Reports-10053.html
http://amiraryani.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/font-size-problem-in-exporting-crystal-report-to-pdf-using-asp-net/

If anybody come across a solution pls. share with me.