# Printing .rpt in a Dot Matrix printer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to print a `.rpt` report but when its printed it shows small fonts is anyone here experienced this also? how to fix this? TIA

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but it's maybe the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819559/crystal-reports-font-issue)

Comment: CR don't manage every kind of fonts. Try to change it and coment us.